# How to differentiate $2^{\sqrt{\log_2n}}$?

Tags: calculus

It's been a while since I took calculus and I just can't figure out how to do this. I'm hoping if someone shows me how it's done I can learn from it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Try using the change of base formula and/or the chain rule on $2^{f(x)}$ and then on $\sqrt{\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(2)}}$. This should also [**help**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Please add a bit more detail.

Comment: Do you know how to find the derivative of $a^n$ with respect to $n$? You write $a^n=e^{n\ln a}$, and then use the chain rule.

Comment: As a rule, don’t use $n$ or $m$ for a variable taking real values. It is not technically a rule, but a lot of people read it as an integer variable. The worst case of this is that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\\\lim_{x\to\infty}$$ mean two different things, in most occurrences, even though there is no “definition” which makes this true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=\implies \ln y=\sqrt{\log_2n}\ln2$$
$$\implies(\ln y)^2=\log_2n(\ln2)^2=(\ln n)(\ln 2)$$
$$\implies2(\ln y)\frac1y\frac{dy}{dn}=\frac1n\ln2$$
$$\implies\frac{dy}{dn}=\frac{y}{\ln y}\cdot\frac{\ln2}{n}$$
$$=\frac{2^{\sqrt{\log_2n}}}{(\ln2)\sqrt{\log_2n}}\cdot\frac{\ln2}{n}$$
$$\implies \frac{dy}{dn}=\frac{2^{\sqrt{\log_2n}}}{2n\sqrt{\log_2n}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that by the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) we have

$$\frac{d}{dn}(2^{n})=\frac{d}{dn}\left(e^{n\ln(2)}\right)=\frac{d}{dn}\left(n\ln(2)\right)e^{n\ln(2)}=2^{n}\ln(2)$$

Then by the change of base formula and chain rule we have

$$\frac{d}{dn}\left(2^{\sqrt{\log_2(n)}}\right)=\frac{d}{dn}\left(2^{\frac{\sqrt{\log(n)}}{\sqrt{\log{2}}}}\right)$$
$$=\frac{d}{du}\left(2^u\right)\frac{du}{dn}$$

where $u={\frac{\sqrt{\log(n)}}{\sqrt{\log{2}}}}.$ Then we know that $\frac{d}{du}\left(2^u\right)=2^{u}\ln(2)$ and

$$\frac{du}{dn}=\frac{d}{dn}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\log n}}{\sqrt{\log 2}}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log2}}\frac{d}{dn}\left(\sqrt{\log n}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log2}}\left(\frac{1}{2n\sqrt{\log n}}\right)$$

again by the chain rule (say with $\frac{d}{dn}\sqrt{\log n}=\frac{d}{dv}\left(\sqrt{v}\right)\frac{dv}{dn}$ where $v=\log(n)$). Combining the above we obtain

$$\frac{d}{dn}\left(2^{\sqrt{\log_2(n)}}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log2}}\left(\frac{1}{2n\sqrt{\log n}}\right)\left(2^{{\frac{\sqrt{\log(n)}}{\sqrt{\log{2}}}}}\log2\right)$$
$$=\frac{2^{{\frac{\sqrt{\log(n)}}{\sqrt{\log{2}}}}}\sqrt{\log{2}}}{2n\sqrt{\log n}}$$